# Android: ListView changing wrong row layout visibility

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with hundred of items. Every item had a couple of LinearLayouts but ONE of them is Visibility.GONE! Every item has textviews and an image. On Image Click i want to set the LinearLayout with visibility.Gone to View.VISIBLE. It works fine until you scroll down the listview, then every 4th item has the same layout set to VISIBLE but i only need the Clicked one! Here is the getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageView imgForClick;
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    final LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);

    imgForClick = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imgForClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are recycling the views, so the layout gets changed on a click and then that layout is used in your other rows to save memory.

You need to remember the state of each of the rows to know whether or not the layout should be visible or not

Have something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
if (shouldBeVisible.get(position)) {
    hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

That way the layout will always be set one way or another.

`shouldBeVisible` is a `List` of something that lets you know which rows should have that layout visible or not.

EDIT--
An alternative is to remove view recycling, however this will dramatically hurt performance and should NOT be done, but I'm just explaining to list all your options.

You would remove the line
`if (convertView == null)`

Making Android always inflate a new view, instead of using the recycled one when possible.

Comment: Reading this is exactly what I needed to remind me of the REUSE of the views. I couldn't figure out why data from other list items were jumping to the top of my ListView.